# Can we create custom data type in AWS Redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift

Can we create custom data type in AWS Redshift just like Oracle? I want to create a new complex type with two attributes like it is defined in the below Oracle code. Is there any workaround to this in Redshift?

Oracle sample code:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TYPE "BUDGET_REPORTING"."T_RESULT_FUNCTIONS_NG" as object (
  codeRet number,--1 success code , 0 error code 
  messageRet varchar2(2500)  -- message error 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Redshift has the Super data type that can store this kind of structured data in a single column.  See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/super-overview.html